# MongoDB - (NodeJS) - find() based on two fields. find from both fields if NEITHER are blank, or just one if the other is blank

Tags: node.js, mongodb, find

CAN SOME ONE please EXPLAIN HOW I CAN AVOID THIS

[MongoDB - find()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkL3R.png) - imgur link

MongoDB - (NodeJS) - find() based on two fields. find from both fields if NEITHER are blank, or just one if the other is blank.

I have looked at the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) for MongoDB. The best thing I've found is this:

```
$and : [
        { $or : [ { price : 0.99 }, { price : 1.99 } ] },
        { $or : [ { sale : true }, { qty : { $lt : 20 } } ] }
    ]
```

Which still doesn't help me.

Comment: Please don't post code as image

Answer (score 1):

Just build your query object dynamically:

```
var query = {};
if (searchParameters.specialty !== '') {
  query.program = searchParameters.specialty;
}
if (searchParameters.state !== '') {
  query.state = searchParameters.state;
}
Model.find(query, ...);
```

(you might also want to ensure that at least one isn't blank, otherwise the query will match *all* documents)